# I need some correction VB.net Code Framework 2.0 making a register system

Tags: vb.net, error-correction

In my program, I want to to check if my app is registered when my progress bar is finished. If it is Registered (checked by the text of a label in form 1) the second textbox should appear and if is not registered the first text box should appear

The problem is that I must add an end `if` when I don't want to because it will continuously pop up the textbox.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ProgressBar1.Value += 1
    If ProgressBar1.Value =
    ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Minimum
        If Form1.Label4.Text = "Unregistered" Then
        MsgBox("Exampletext", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Me.Hide()
    Else
        MsgBox("Exampletext1", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Hide()
    End If
End Sub 
End Class
```

BTW: I didn't wanted to make it in `framework 2.0` but I made it, to make it more compatible with older Windows.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense.  I have no idea what you're actually asking for.  Please try editing your question and providing a FULL and CLEAR description of the problem.

Comment: I will be off for an hour so if you want answer  and i will see all the answers then

Comment: Just remove your else statement and the messageBox will pop up only when it's done...

Comment: can you please explain that ? i want to check if my app is registered if yes messagebox with Exampletext1 will appear if it is unregistered Exampletext will appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why correct indentation is important...

The compiler thinks that the `Else` is related to the first `If`.

And actually, nothing will ever happen when your second `If` is correct because there is no `End If`. Therefore it is assuming that the instruction is on the same line.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
ProgressBar1.Value += 1
    If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Minimum
        If Form1.Label4.Text = "Unregistered" Then
            MsgBox("Exampletext", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            Me.Hide()
        Else
            MsgBox("Exampletext1", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            Hide()
        End If
    End If 'You need to add the End If here
End Sub
```

I am however voting to close this question as it is a typo error...

Comment: thank you my problem is now solved :) have a nice day :)

Comment: Please mark this answer as the correct one by clicking the tick mark on the answer.

Comment: @MichaelSelvesakis Please mark this answer as the correct one by clicking the tick mark on the answer.